# Modal Dialog is Loaded But Invisible

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I tried to make a modal. I use AJAX to show the modal but the modal is invisible. When I use the button's trigger with data-toggle and data-target, the modal is showing up visible.

This is what I have tried to do

- Check that all script is correctly loaded
- Tried to reorder script
- Delete fade class in modal and the modal visible but with bad UI
- Change bootstrap version but result is same

This is my code

AJAX

```js
$("body").on("click", ".btn-show", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var me = $(this),
    url = me.attr("href"),
    title = me.attr("title");

  $("#modal-title").text(title);

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (response) {
      $("#modal-body").html(response);
      $("#modal").modal("show");
    },
  });
});
```

HTML Modal

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" id="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Form Input</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer" id="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
          Close
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modal-btn-save">Save
          changes
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SS modal exists but is not visible:

[image]

Comment: In the first line of your ajax, you are selecting `.btn-show`, but where is that in the HTML? What are you selecting?

Comment: that selecting my link . i put in separate file .

Comment: `<a href="{{ $url_show }}" class="btn-show"><i class="fa fa-eye" style="color: #093697; padding-right: 10px;"></i></a>`

Comment: Hi barkah. We can see there's nothing wrong with the modal or the click event handling by stripping out the ajax call and just firing the modal('show') in the click handler - the modal appears just fine. 

So the code to display it likely isn't being reached, i.e. your AJAX call isn't reaching "success". So we need to see more of your code (that responds to the AJAX) or some more debug information from your browsers developer console. At very least add an error handler to the AJAX that console logs or alerts the fact it failed to guide you in the right direction.

Comment: can you give me sample an error handler to  show logs or alert in AJAX.?

Answer (score 1):

There are no errors with the modal, and the `$("#modal").modal("show");` displays the modal just fine (see code snippet below),

Since the code snippet below works fine, it seems clear that the original code's "success" function is never called:

```js
success: function (response) {
  $("#modal-body").html(response);
  $("#modal").modal("show");
}
```

I suggest adding an error function to the [ajax parameters](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```js
error: function (jsXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  // handle error here
}
```

From the jQuery docs:

> **error**
>   Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
>   A function to be called if the request fails.

```js
function showModal() {
  $("#modal-title").text('Sample Title');
  $("#modal-body").html('Sample Response');
  $("#modal").modal("show");
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- scripts needed by Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body class="p-2">
  <button onclick="showModal()">Show Modal</button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" id="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Form Input</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer" id="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
          Close
        </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modal-btn-save">Save
          changes
        </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: i tried to check the status response, everything is OK in console log. And i tried to remove `<div class="modal fade">` with `<div class="modal">` only. The modal is showing up and visible.  This is what makes me confused

Comment: @barkah Can you confirm that a simple call to `$("#modal").modal("show")` works or not?

Comment: It looks like we're missing a lot of your code, if the ajax response is success then the code you've posted above does work, but if it doesn't within your larger project then there's some other interaction going on that we can't see from the example you've provided.

Comment: @terrymorse i tried put `$('#modal').modal('show');
            if($('#modal').modal('show')){
                console.log('Success');
            }`  . and in my console show Success word

Comment: @Andrew actually,i think not much interaction that i used to in my code. But thank you for your response

Comment: @barkah But does it display the modal or not?

Comment: @terrymorse the modal still invisible. The modal only visible when i delete fade class. I don't know why, what i missing some script needed?

Comment: this is SS when i'm not using modal fade https://imgur.com/vj4nskL

Comment: Now, i guest in my ajax need something to load fade animation but i don't know what, because when i make modal fade with a button trigger without AJAX , the modal is show up correctly.

Comment: [SOLVED] i tried to change bootstrap old version . 3.3.7 . And i don't know why the modal its finally work. Before, i only change bootstrap 4 version

Answer (score 1):

I just fix this problem on Laravel Voyager Admin.

This is because I just declare two times bootstrap scripts.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case the code relied on the "fade in" animation to  properly display the modal and my code only had the "fade" class. So, while it was adding the class "show" to the modal, the property would stay with opacity 0 due to the animation overlapping it.

Original code with bug:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" role="dialog" >
```

My fix:

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="modal" role="dialog" >
```